# H2 in memory Database doesnt create table when starting application

Tags: database, h2

i have an issue where my sql-statements, doesnt get created when i start my application.
My yaml-file looks like that:

```
Spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=h2;LOCK_MODE=0;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'createTable-0.sql';
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  h2:
    console.enabled: true
    console.path: /h2
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

However when i start my application, no table is created:
[H2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVsJk.png)

My Projectstructure looks like that:
[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x0jR.png)

I tried to change the path of the createTable sql or changed some configurations on the yaml file, however it didnt worked and still no table was created when starting up the app.
I know that the sql is correct, since manually pasting it in the h2 browser , the tables are created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the following:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`
```

Try this and do let know if it works

Comment: Done it, but the table didnt get created still.